# Unit testing sockets

Tags: php, unit-testing, sockets

Greetings Stackoverflowers,

I have an application in which a communication abstraction layer exists. Each implementation in this layer, called a *connector*, provides my application with a way of exchanging data with a connected peer (e.g.: through HTTP, TCP sockets, UDP sockets, etc.).

Per example, I have a `Connector_Tcp` class that implements methods such as *read*, *write*, *open* and *close*.

I need to write a unit test for that class. I know that unit tests should have as less dependencies as possible. Unfortunately, in that case, the dependency is a system resource: a socket; and I cannot bypass it.

**I need some advice on how to go about unit testing this class.**

In my opinion, even though this class is using a system resource, it should be tested as all the other *connectors* to make sure that it respects the standard established by my application.

I am concerned about such things as binding collisions (*Address already in use* errors) and blocking. I don't want the unit test to fail because the port is already in use by a system service that has nothing to do with my application.

I have done a lot of unit tests in my days, but none of which relies on such a low-level resource that are sockets.

How would you go about unit testing a socket-dependent class? Open a socket for every unit? Use a single server class, then a manually-defined socket resource to connect to it and test it...?

I guess my problem really is the following:

If the unit test fails... how do I know if:

- The socket is already in use by another process;
- The unit test is badly written; or
- The method behaves improperly (which is what a unit test is worth).

**I need the unit test to test only if the method has been behaving properly or not...**

Comment: I haven't done any real PHP development, but can you create a mock class that is derived from your Socket class?

Comment: @Dave: I can. I use mock objects for every single class that requires a connector. My problem here is: I need to test the socket class itself to make sure it respects the abstraction layer's conventions... By testing a mock object, it doesn't clearly tells me whether the socket class works or not.

Comment: there's a practical limit to what you can unit test in my opinion.  I wouldn't try to unit test the socket.  I guess in your case, since the socket could be accessible outside of your application, you just have to do the best you can to write unit tests around the connector and make sure it handles all of the exceptional conditions.  You mentioned "address already in use" errors, so one thing I would do is make sure my connector didn't just die because of this condition.  I would make a unit test create this condition and ensure that it catches it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've written a similar abstraction layer, albeit in C/C++, and I have had occasion to unit-test the socket based code. I don't know if there's anything inherently specific to PHP here, so I'll just offer what generic advice I can.

- Create a server socket in your setup, close it in the tear down. Depending on whether you support many clients connecting to the server socket, you may want to do that part in the test method.
- Assuming you can specify the port to connect to in your client code, have the server socket bind to port 0 (ephemeral port), and then use this in the client code. This will eliminate the problem of binding to a port already in use.
- Set timeouts on your sockets. If your test fails for some unexpected reason, you don't want it hanging waiting for a connection forever.
- You need to be able to interleave the client/server behaviour. For example, you'll want to test what happens if the server shuts down its side of the connection half way through a client read/write. Either asynchronous I/O or multi-threading will do the job. I'm not sure what you have at your disposal in PHP.

Comment: I think I needed advice from a C programmer, because of the way PHP sockets are handled. Socket functions in PHP are very similar to C sockets (they even use the same constant names!). That being said, I think you had pointed me in the right direction. By binding on port 0 and using `getsockname`, I can retrieve the port number to which the server has bound and connect a client to it, without having to worry about ports already being used. I should have thought about it earlier! Thank you very much!

Comment: Oh and for multi-threading and multiple concurrent connections, I have don't to worry about it. There's another class taking care of this, so all I need here is to test the socket itself.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I'm understanding your question properly ... if not, please let me know. But what I would do is mock the socket. That would let you write a series of unit tests that ensure that your method does all the right things in various cases.

For example, you could write one unit test that tells the socket mock instance to throw a "port not available" exception. In that case, you could assert that your method caught the exception and logged it with the same text that was in the exception.

And even more central to the issue, you could write a unit test that tells the socket mock instance to return a valid stream of bytes from read(), and then you could assert that your method does the right thing(s) with those bytes.

So you're not actually testing the socket. You're setting up the socket to simulate certain occurrences, and you're testing to see if your code that works with the socket is doing the right things.

(I've used mocking frameworks in Java, C#, Ruby and JavaScript. I've never worked with PHP, but I bet there are some good mocking frameworks out there for it).

EDIT: Yes, there are some mocking frameworks for PHP out there. I can't recommend one, but here are a couple I was able to find: [PHPUnit](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.0/en/mock-objects.html) and [LastCraft](http://www.lastcraft.com/mock_objects_documentation.php)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am already using PHPUnit. Unfortunately, unlike Java and C#, which I also know, sockets in PHP are very close to C/C++ sockets. In fact, PHP uses a wrapper for the C library. PHP sockets are not objects, but are considered resources (more or less pointers), which are more like a primitive type, thus cannot be mocked. My classes are wrappers for those socket functions, and I need to make sure that they return *false*, *null* or data when they have to, without failing because of collisions. I think @axw might have the answer I need. Thanks a lot though!